# How to close only one stage in Java FX (without exiting all app)?

Tags: javafx

I know about System.exit(0) and Platform.exit() and stage.close() but all of those kill all of stages. Any ideas how can I kill one stage? I mean kill/close, not hide.

EDIT: 
I'll explain exactly what my problem is. 
I've got class like this:

```
public class Controller extends Application implements Serializable {

private LineChart<String,Number> lineChart;

public void btn(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart,400,400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.setOnCloseRequest( e-> stage.hide());
    }
}
```

I create a new LineChart in Controllers constructor. The problem is when I call the btn() method for a second (and more) time on the same Controller... I got error "IllegalArgumentException: LineChart is already set as root of another scene". When I call Platform.exit()/stage.close()/stage.hide()/System.exit(0) as setOnCloseRequest my main window (with menu etc) is also closing, and what I excpect is closing nothing more than window with LineChart.

Comment: `Stage.close`, which is equivalent to `Stage.hide`, only closes the one `Stage` (and its descendants, if any). What makes you think it will close all stages? Also, the way to "kill/close" a stage in JavaFX _is_ to hide it. Can you clarify more about what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: Alternatively show a [mcve] of a application that closes multiple windows when you close one of them...

Comment: I've added explanation to my post, it's more clear now

Comment: Unfortunately, your example is neither _complete_ nor _verifiable_. From the code you've shown, along with your explanation, it's clear why you get the `IllegalArgumentException` but it still _isn't_ clear how closing the one `Stage` is closing the others. Please include a [mcve] that we can copy-paste onto our own machines and run as is. That way we can observe the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a runnable example program to show you how to close 1 window or all windows

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        createLinechart();

        Button newWindowButton = new Button("Create window");
        newWindowButton.setOnAction(event -> createWindow());

        Scene scene = new Scene(newWindowButton);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createWindow(){
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.getChildren().add(lineChart);

        Button stageCloseButton = new Button("stage.close();");
        Button platformExitButton = new Button("Platform.exit()");
        Button systemExitButton = new Button("System.exit(0)");

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(stageCloseButton,platformExitButton,systemExitButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        Stage stage  = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stageCloseButton.setOnAction(event -> stage.close());
        platformExitButton.setOnAction(event -> Platform.exit());
        systemExitButton.setOnAction(event -> System.exit(0));
    }

    private void createLinechart(){
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
        //creating the chart
        lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

        lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
        //defining a series
        XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
        series.setName("My portfolio");
        //populating the series with data
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 23));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, 14));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, 24));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(5, 34));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 36));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 22));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 45));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 43));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 17));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 29));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 25));

        lineChart.getData().add(series);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

See how calling `stage.close()` doesn't close all of the windows but the other two do thats how you close only one window.